# Install NVIDIA GTX graphics driver on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux, graphics

I can't get my NVIDIA graphics card to run on Linux Mint 17.1. All I get is a black screen. I tried installing the driver with

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and according to the NVIDIA procedure.

@arielCo:

1. I have two kernels installed. It booted `3.13.0-37-generic`.
2. `/lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/` only contains three files:

   - vboxguest.ko
   - vboxsf.ko
   - vboxvideo.ko
3. `lsmod | grep -e nvidia -e nouveau` gives

   `nouveau              1097199  0 
   mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
   video                  19476  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi
   ttm                    85150  1 nouveau
   i2c_algo_bit           13413  2 i915,nouveau
   drm_kms_helper         55071  2 i915,nouveau
   drm                   303102  6 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
   wmi                    19177  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi`
4. The directory `/usr/lib/nvidia-346` is present. 
   There are also a

   - `/usr/lib/nvidia`and a
   - `/usr/lib/nvidia-346-prime`.
5. `less -p "nvidia|nouveau" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` results in

   `Pattern not found`.
6. I can post my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, but it's rather long. No word of `nouveau` or `nvidia`.

Comment: Check that your version of the drivers supports your card. In terms of general functionality, I think the proprietary drivers beat Nouveau. I'd certainly try to get the former to work.

Comment: I did. The 346 does support my card.

Comment: Ok, then for the record, perhaps state what driver and card you are using.

Comment: I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 and I was using the xorg-edgers nvidia-346 driver (346.35).

Comment: Can you post your xorg log?

Answer (score 1):

The NVIDIA drivers could be easily installed in Linux Mint 17.1 through the CUDA toolkit:

1. Download the CUDA 7.0 network installer for Ubuntu 14.04 (which Mint is based on) and install it:

   ```
   wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
   dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install CUDA: `sudo apt-get install cuda`
3. Reboot. At first everything will going apparently wrong because your Cinnamon will crash. Do not worry; just launch the **Driver Manager** application and select the **340.x** version of the recently installed NVIDIA driver.
4. Reboot again. Now I recommend that you edit your `xorg.conf` file: `sudoedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` (please do a backup before) and modify the NVIDIA Device section:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier "nvidia"
       Driver "nvidia"
       BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
       Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
       Option "UseEditDpi" "False"
       Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
   EndSection
   ```
5. Basically you have to add these two lines:

   ```
       Option "UseEditDpi" "False"
       Option "DPI" "96 x 96"
   ```
6. Reboot one more time and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether the installation succeeded; `dpkg -l nvidia\*` should tell the state of the packages and the output from `apt-get install nvidia-346` should give clues if it didn't work.

I use the same PPA in Ubuntu with a GTX 670; you can do several things to compare to my system:

- Boot in Recovery Mode, then run a root shell.
- Even if it installed, the module built at installation time must match the kernel version. Running `modinfo nvidia-346` should produce something like:

  ```
  filename:       /lib/modules/YOUR_KERNEL_VERSION/updates/dkms/nvidia_346.ko
  alias:          char-major-195-*
  version:        346.35
  supported:      external
  license:        NVIDIA
  alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000E00sv*sd*bc04sc80i00*
  alias:          pci:v000010DEd00000AA3sv*sd*bc0Bsc40i00*
  alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
  alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
  ...
  ```

  You may have several directories under `/lib/modules`, one for each installed kernel; `uname -r` will tell you what you booted with. See which module(s) you have with `ls -l /lib/modules/*/updates/dkms/nvidia_346.ko`.
- The module should load before even X starts (run `lsmod | grep -e nvidia -e nouveau` from a console).
- The actual proprietary driver is installed to `/usr/lib/nvidia-346`.
- Run `less -p "nvidia|nouveau" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`. In my log, Nouveau loads and unloads, then nvidia proceeds.

Try these, note any significant differences, and post the contents of your `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: I have some significant differences. I added them to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is for a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.1 (Rebecca)

```
update completely sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade

Add 'nomodeset' to the grub loader i.e. sudo vi /etc/default/grub should look like this:

    *GRUB_DEFAULT=0
    #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
    GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
    GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

> **install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia bbswitch-dkms primus**
>
> Through synaptic package manager because there are dependancies for these
>   three that didn't show up on the apt-get call
>
> **sudo apt-get install libcuda1-331 libvdpau1 nvidia-331 nvidia-331-uvm
>   nvidia-libopencl1-331 nvidia-opencl-icd-331 nvidia-settings
>   screen-resolution-extra**

```
 gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

Change:
 The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),

auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau

(See also the driver-specific sections below)

Driver=

to:The Driver used by Bumblebee server. If this value is not set (or empty),

 auto-detection is performed. The available drivers are nvidia and nouveau

 (See also the driver-specific sections below)

**Driver=nvidia** 

Also change:

 Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]

 Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset

KernelDriver=nvidia-current

PMMethod=auto

 colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries

LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib32/nvidia-current

 comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the

 default Xorg modules path

XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

to:

-Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia

-[driver-nvidia]

-Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset

KernelDriver=nvidia-331

PMMethod=auto

 colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries

LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331

 comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the

 default Xorg modules path

XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`

Finally save the file, reboot and then test vblank_mode=0 glxgears you should 

get a high frame rate using the dedicated graphics chip.
```

You can also run programs with the dedicated graphics using optirun

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && 

sudo apt update && 

sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Can you explain, please, why you would expect the `nvidia-352` to work where the OP has already stated that `nvidia-346` doesn't. Generally on U&L SE we would prefer answers that explain a solution.

Comment: Your comment is backward, the actual question would be, why would you expect the older, out of current status driver to work better than the newer release, that includes bug fixes, card version support updates, etc? For a card as new as the poster has, you want the newest driver, not some crusty old packaged version that shouldn't even be offered to users as a current driver for the card type he has, but rather just as a fallback to be used if and only if the current nvidia stable driver, which is 355.11 as of today, fails. I used to support mint, briefly, but no more, so will leave it there.